# Adding class to element up the DOM tree

Tags: jquery

I am working with a list like this:

```
<ul class="leftmenu">

    <li class="selected primary"><a href="index.php" title="Admin Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Admin Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="ipro_toggle primary"><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Site Settings <i class="arrow fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>

        <ul class="secondary ipro_toggle_content">
            <li><a href="set_configuration.php" title="Configuration"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Configuration</a></li>
            <li><a href="set_styles.php" title="Styles"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Styles</a></li>
            <li><a href="set_access.php" title="Access"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="set_announcements.php" title="Announcements"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Announcements</a></li>
            <li><a href="set_misc.php" title="Miscellaneous"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Miscellaneous</a></li>
        </ul>

    <li class="primary"><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Campaign Tracking</a></li>
    <li class="primary"><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Referral Tracking</a></li>
    <li class="primary"><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Testimonials <em>3</em></a></li>
    <li class="primary"><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>Sales Stats</a></li>
    <li class="primary"><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Client Communications</a></li>
    <li class="ipro_toggle primary"><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Users <i class="arrow fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>

        <ul class="secondary ipro_toggle_content">
            <li><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Add User</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Modify User</a></li>
        </ul>

    <li class="primary"><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to add a class to the closest `ul.leftmenu .iprotoggle` (it's parent li) on page load. Here is what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var thisUrl = window.location.href;

  $("ul.leftmenu li a").each(function() {

        var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');

        if (thisUrl === thisHref) { // if url found
            $(this).closest(".ipro_toggle_content").slideToggle(); // This works
            $(this).closest("li.ipro_toggle").addClass('selected'); // This doesn't

        }

  });

});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That should work. Is there an `<a>` which satisfies the condition `if (thisUrl === thisHref) {` with parent as `ipro_toggle `

Comment: @ShaunakD Yes there is, which is why the `slideToggle()` works.

Comment: May be that does not work because you have a `<ul>` inside `<ul>`. That is invalid html.

Comment: have you tried find() instead?

Comment: @StuartWickenden I just tried it, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @JROB, all children `a` with `li.ipro_toggle` as parent have `href="#"`. So it will work only if `window.location.href` will return `#`. Also I think your inner`<ul>` elements should be inside `<li>`

Comment: agreeing with @ShaunakD , the html section you have shown is invalid. You cannot nest ul inside another ul. it can be nested only inside li tage of a ul.